# I am unable to implement the setOnClickListener() for my button

Tags: android, sql, onclick, buttonclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to create an SQL database in Android. I am currently following an online tutorial but every time I try to add an OnClickListener for my button I get the following error message...

`The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments(SqlExample).`

In the quick fix eclipse allows me to implement an OnClickListener however I end up with the following import "public class SqlExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.view.View.OnClickListener"....  Is this correct? It is something I have never seen before.

Comment: it is an import problem. make sure you import View.OnClickListener

Comment: ya correct and go ahead then its gives you onclick method and you can write code in onclick method what you want onbutton click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add thiss line `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` to the import section.

```
private final OnClickListener yourButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {

        //Your code

    }
};
```

Comment: Here is my code...
import android.app.Activity;

public class SqlExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

      Button updateButton;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlexample);
        updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        sqlDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idView);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        coordinates = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCoordinates);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

Comment: try changing the  
`implements OnClickListener` 
to 
`implements View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code according to this sort of pattern.

```
// NAME OF THE ANDROID COMPONENT. REPLACE WITH BUTTON
Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybtnid);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) {
          // PLACE YOUR CLICK CODE HERE..
}
```

});

This works!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, do Ctrl+Shift+O for any such things and all imports will be automatically added.